# c# namespaces for SQL management, used for sql server backup

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, .net-4.0

I am trying to pragmatically run a backup of an SQL Server database using C# .NET 3.5/4.0.  I have found out how to accomplish this, however I can't seem to find the namespace libraries that are used for the backup.

I am looking for the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management libraries, I just can't find these anywhere. I have installed SQL Server 2005 Enterprise and all of the tools samples and the libraries still don't seem to appear in visual studio (version 2010)

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find them under:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\SDK\Assemblies"

(Thats on my 64-bit machine for SQL 2008.)
You need all three of the following assemblies:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum.dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Assemblies for SMO and the like exist under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies` (adjust for appropriate bitness of your machine and SQL Server version - I think 2005 would be `\90\` rather than `\100\`